# autoload and namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.3, autoload

I've been working with PHP for a long time, but am now starting to experiment with newer language features such as namespaces.  I have a question regarding autoloading that I haven't been able to find an adequate answer to in my web searching.

Suppose I have classes in different namespaces:

```
namespace foo\bar\baz;

class Quux
{
}

namespace fred\barney\wilma;

class Betty
{
}
```

Then suppose I had an autoloader that assumes that there's a 1:1 mapping between namespaces and directory structures:

```
function autoload ($className)
{
    $className = str_replace ('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR, $className);
    include ($className . 'php');
}

spl_autoload_register ('autoload');
```

Does the fully qualified namespace get passed to the autoloader under all circumstances, or does the autoloader need to take the namespace currently being used into account?

For example, if I do the following:

```
$a = new \foo\bar\baz\Quux;
$b = new \fred\barney\wilma\Betty;
```

the autoloader should work fine.

But what if I do the following?

```
use \foo\bar\baz as FBB;
$a = new Quux;
$b = new \fred\barney\wilma\Betty;
```

When attempting to instantiate a new Quux, will the autoloader still get `\foo\bar\baz\Quux` as the class name argument?  Or should it get `FBB\Quux`, or even just `Quux`?

If the latter, can I determine the namespace the class is supposed to be in from within my autoloader by using `__NAMESPACE__` or some other such mechanism?

Comment: So what is the result you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autoloader will get `foo\bar\baz\Quux` as the class name argument.

> **Namespace name definitions**
>   Unqualified name 
> This is an identifier
>   without a namespace separator, such as Foo
>
> Qualified name 
> This is an identifier with a namespace separator, such
>   as Foo\Bar
>
> Fully qualified name 
> This is an identifier with a namespace separator
>   that begins with a namespace separator, such as \Foo\Bar.
>   namespace\Foo is also a fully qualified name.

And the the rule is :

> All unqualified and qualified names (not fully qualified names) are
>   translated during compilation according to current import rules. For
>   example, if the namespace A\B\C is imported as C, a call to C\D\e() is
>   translated to A\B\C\D\e().

Comment: Sorry, but I had to unaccept this answer I'm afraid.  When I tried actually implementing an autoloader that worked like this, I found that it worked okay for `new /foo/bar/baz ()`, but if I did `use /foo/bar; new baz()` I'd only get baz being passed to my autoloader.

Comment: @GordonM You should do `use foo\bar\baz; new baz();`.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out.  Sorry about that, I'd just totally misunderstood how the use keyword worked.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a *fully qualified namespace name* (without leading backslash).

This also applies to all other dynamic language constructs and functions in PHP:

If you write `$obj = new $class` the `$class` must be fully qualified and doesn't use any defined aliases.
If you write `class_exists($class)` the `$class` must also be fully qualified.
And same applies to autoload: It is passed the fully qualified name.

(The only exception to this rule I know of is the `define` function, which can define constants both using fully qualified names, but also using an unqualified name, in which case it will be defined in the current namespace.)